# Using gulp-sass, how do I preserve the folder structure of my sass files except for the immediate parent directory?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I have a project with multiple folders that contain sass files:

```
|── src
    └── scripts
        └── app1
            └── sass
                └── base.scss
        └── app2
            └── sass
                └── base.scss
```

I also have a gulp task that compiles those `.scss` files using `gulp-sass` and `gulp-concat-css`:

```
gulp.task('build:sass', () =>
    gulp.src([
      'scripts/**/*.scss'
    ])
    .pipe(plugins.sass().on('error', plugins.sass.logError))
    .pipe(plugins.concatCss('bundle.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  );
```

Right now, the above task just creates `bundle.css` into the `dist` folder:

```
|── dist
    └── bundle.css
```

What I'd like to have happen is this, where the initial folder structure is preserved, except for the `sass` folder is now `css`.

```
|── dist
    └── scripts
        └── app1
            └── css
                └── bundle.css
        └── app2
            └── css
                └── bundle.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`gulp-flatmap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatmap) plugin to solve this:

```
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('build:sass', () =>
  gulp.src('scripts/app*/')
    .pipe(plugins.flatmap((stream, dir) =>
       gulp.src(dir.path + '/**/*.scss')
         .pipe(plugins.sass().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(plugins.concatCss('css/bundle.css'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/' + path.basename(dir.path)))
    )) 
);
```

This selects all of your `app` directories and then maps each of those directories to a new stream in which all `.scss` files in that particular directory are concatenated into a single `bundle.css` file.