# Keep folder structure with concat() in gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

Folder structure:

```
project
|
+-coffee
| |
| +-main.coffee
| |
| +-testDir
| | |
| | +-models.coffee
| | |
| | +-views.coffee
| |
| +-anotherDir
| | |
| | +-routes.coffee
| | |
| | +-views.coffee
| | |
| | +-modules.coffee
| |
| +- etc...
| 
+-www
```

The idea is to keep the folder structure from the `coffee/` directory when writing files to the `www/` directory. There can be an arbitrary number of subfolders in `coffee/`. All `.coffee` files from each folder should be concatened into a `modules.js` file:

```
www
|
+-modules.js
|
+-testDir
| |
| +-modules.js
|
+-anotherDir
| |
| +-modules.js
|
+- etc...
```

I currently have this gulp task:

```
gulp.task('coffee', function() {
    gulp.src('./coffee/**/*.coffee', {base: './coffee/'})
        .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(uglify())
        // .pipe(concat('modules.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'))
});
```

Without the `concat()` the files are placed into the correct subfolders (but they're not concatened). With the `concat()` all files are concatened into a single `modules.js` file:

```
www
|
+-modules.js
```

How I can realize this correctly?

Comment: Unclear. You need to give a better example. Do you want all files of every directory to be concatenated in a separate `modules.js` file? Or do you want just two `modules.js` files (one for test and one for the rest)?

Comment: `all files of every directory to be concatenated in a separate modules.js file` if in coffee folder many dirs  test1 test2 ... test100  in www must be same folder structure with modules.js inside in each folder.

Comment: You're supposed to edit the example in your question to better explain what you want (for example what about multiple subdirectory levels?).

Comment: in this project there is no sub levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gulp-sass, how do I preserve the folder structure of my sass files except for the immediate parent directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922990/using-gulp-sass-how-do-i-preserve-the-folder-structure-of-my-sass-files-except)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`gulp-flatmap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatmap):

```
var flatmap = require('gulp-flatmap');

gulp.task('coffee', function() {
  return gulp.src('./coffee/{*,}/', {base:'./coffee'})
    .pipe(flatmap(function(stream, dir) {
       return gulp.src(dir.path + '/*.coffee')
         .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gutil.log))
         .pipe(uglify())
         .pipe(concat('modules.js'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/' + path.relative(dir.base, dir.path)))
     })) 
});
```

This first puts the `coffee/` directory and all of its direct subdirectories in a stream. Each of those directories then gets mapped to a new stream that concatenates all `.coffee` files in the respective directory. Finally the appropriate destination folder for each resulting `modules.js` file is determined by using [`path.relative()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to).

Comment: Thank you very much. i didnt know about flatmap.