# gulp-concat for each project using wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I have *N* projects that has the same structure and all the projects are inside `src` path:

```
projectName/

├── index.html
├── anotherPage.html
└── assets/
        ├── css/
        │   └── {bunchofstyles}.css
        ├── imgs/
        │   └── {bunchofimages}.{someImageFormat}
        └──js/
            └── {bunchofjs}.js
```

I want to join the css files into one, same for the javascript files. Im using gulp for this with gulp-concat, for example, for the js I have something similar to this:

```
//this was made by memory, if its wrong dont pay attention to the minnor details
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

gulp.task("joinJSFiles", function(){
    gulp.src("./src/**/assets/js/*.js")
        .pipe(concat("script.js"))
        .gulp.dest("./dist")
})
```

But I have the following issues:

1. concat joins all the files that are in the gulp.src, including of other projects
2. concat deletes the structure of my project, saving the file into dist root instead of having the same structure
3. Optional: I have two tasks that make the same thing but for different extension, one for js and another for css, can I have a single task to get this approach?

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could glob on the projectName level and then gulp-foreach from there.

Comment: @Mark can you give me an example? I dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion that @Mark made, I made a gulp task that loops over each project but instead of `gulp-foreach` I used `gulp-flatmap` (I think its the same thing) and followed the following SO anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933109/4637140

So my gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('joinJSFiles', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/*')
     .pipe(flatmap(function(steam, dir){
        return gulp.src(dir.path + "/assets/js/*.js", {base:dir.path})
          .pipe(concat("script.js"))
          .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"+path.relative(dir.base, dir.path+"/assets/js")))
  }))
});
```

Comment: Glad you got it.  I wasn't able to get back to this until just now.

Answer (score 0):

Define config which has path to all the libraries.

```
var config = {
    js : {
        libsSrc : [
            path.src + "js/libs/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.js",
            path.src + "js/libs/jquery/jquery.js",
        ],
        libsBundleName : "libs-bundle",

        // JS Custom
        customSrc : [
            path.src + "js/custom.js"
        ],
        customBundleName : "custom-bundle"
    },

    // Themes and Styles
    css : {
        // CSS Imports
        libsSrc : [
            path.dist + "themes/libs/custom-bootstrap.css",
            path.dist + "themes/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"
        ],
        libsBundleName : "libs-bundle",

        // CSS Custom
        customSrc : [

        ],
        customBundleName : ""
    }

}
```

Then write gulp tasks for bundling JS and CSS

```
gulp.task('bundle-scripts', ['scripts'], function()  {
    // JS Destination path
    var jsDestPath = path.dist.concat('scripts/bundles');

    // Libs
    var libsTask = gulp.src(config.js.libsSrc)
        .pipe(concat(config.js.libsBundleName + ".js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDestPath))
        .pipe(rename(config.js.libsBundleName + ".min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDestPath));

    // Custom Code
    var customJsTask = gulp.src(config.js.customSrc)
        .pipe(concat(config.js.customBundleName + ".js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDestPath));

    return eventStream.concat(libsTask, customJsTask);
});


gulp.task('bundle-themes', ['fonts', 'sass'], function()  {
    // JS Destination path
    var cssDestPath = path.dist + 'themes/bundles';

    // Libs
    var libTask = gulp.src(config.css.libsSrc)
        .pipe(concat(config.css.libsBundleName + ".min.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDestPath));

    return eventStream.concat(libTask);
});
```

This way you can control everything from the `config` variable

Comment: I dont want to hardcore the files name, it may change from project to project